# Django inline, conditional readonly

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to have the inlines that have some tag (a hidden field) as readonly, but the user will be able to add another and change the lines that dont have that tag.

I've been searching for a while, but I only found how to make a field readonly, when I need to have the whole line, but not all lines.

[image: Example]

The first line I need to be readonly [ checked ]

The second line I need that the user can change [  ]

The third line is the input line, need to be editable [  ]